# Python - Compare multiple text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, unix

I am using the following command to get the list of text files that starts with abc

```
filename = "ls abc*.txt"
os.system(filename)
print filename
```

The result obtained from the above command is

```
abc_first.txt 
abc_second.txt 
abc_third.txt
```

I have an text file with some contents named "**test.txt**"

I need to compare the contents of test.txt with each of above text files and print the matched
line and file names recursively

For example:

`test.txt` is having following contents

```
123
456
789
```

`abc_first.txt` is having following contents

```
789
132
111
```

`abc_second.txt` is having following contents

```
123
abc
ccf
```

The result needs to be

```
filename: abc_first.txt
common : 789

filename : abc_second.txt
common: 123
```

Can anyone help me out with python ?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**, nor a code-writing service. It is [not possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/) to "help you", because that is not a specific question - we have no way to know what you need help with, what you don't understand about it, or how to help. Please try to solve the problem yourself first (this starts with breaking the problem down into logical steps), and figure out *specifically* what you need help with and *what help* you need.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: for few files I would use manually programs like [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) which uses program `diff`. But python has also standard module `difflib`. But maybe you should simply read data, split to list of words and convert to `set()` and calculate `set1 - set2` to get difference. or `set1 & set2` to get common items. Similar question was yesterday.

Comment: using `os.system("ls ...")` is useless - better use `all_filenames = os.listdir()` to get all files  in folder as list in python and later filter this list. Or `all_filenames = glob.glob("abc*.txt")` to get directly list with filtered names.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem was yesterday.

Read files, split into list of lines, convert to `set()` and simply do `set1 & set2`

---

I use `io` only to create file in memory - so everyone can simply copy and run it - but you should use `open()`

```
import io

text0 = '''123
456
789'''

text1 = '''789
132
111'''

text2 = '''123
abc
ccf'''

#with open("test.txt") as fh:
with io.StringIO(text0) as fh:
    lines = fh.read().strip().split('\n')
    set0 = set(lines)

#with open("abc_first.txt") as fh:
with io.StringIO(text1) as fh:
    lines = fh.read().strip().split('\n')
    set1 = set(lines)

#with open("abc_second.txt") as fh:
with io.StringIO(text2) as fh:
    lines = fh.read().strip().split('\n')
    set2 = set(lines)

print( set0 & set1 )
print( set0 & set2 )
```

Result:

```
{'789'}
{'123'}
```